# CSS3 word rotate & translate animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Here is my @keyframes. I want to make a word animation,for example "Hello" word will surround 360 degree with an earth. but, it will  move smoothly -360 degree around the earth. the word will not be upside down.   My @keyframes is wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

```
  @keyframes move {
        from {
            transform: translate(-100px);
            rotateY(0deg)
            transform-origin: 100px;
        }
        to {
            transform: translate(-200px);
        rotateY(-360deg)
            transform-origin: 150px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a working snippet please?

Comment: By the way, your css is invalid. Remove the `;` after the `translate` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need more little things to accomplish that, first give to the text parent `perspective` and `transform-style: preserve-3d`. and for text, instead of using `translateX` use `translateZ`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9qhg1tvr/

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding-left: 200px
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  width: 100px;height:100px;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotateY(40deg);
  animation: rotate 4s linear forwards infinite;
  transform-origin: right center
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px); }
  50% { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(400px); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(0px); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Earth-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="earth">
  <p>
    hello
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: That's what i want. However, i want to ask if i want to move horizontally for a while and then rotate.  How to make it?

Comment: Then make a frame such 25% and use `translateX` with resetting the rotation in it https://jsfiddle.net/9qhg1tvr/1/ .

Answer (score 4):

If you are aiming for a 2D animation, this is a quick and dirty solution.

```css
@import 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css';
html{ padding:10px; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase }
span{ display:inline-block; transform:translateY(50px) }
#ch1{ transform:rotateZ(-45deg); transform-origin:100% 200% }
#ch2{ transform:rotateZ(-30deg); transform-origin:0% 100% }
#ch3{ transform:translateX(5px) translateY(-3px) }
#ch4{ transform:rotateZ(45deg); transform-origin:130% 170% }
#ch5{ transform:rotateZ(33deg); transform-origin:-70% 330% }
#earth{ 
  width:100px; height:100px; background:deepskyblue;
  border-radius:100%; line-height:100px; margin:0 auto;
  transform:translateY(70px)
}
#curve{ 
  animation-name:orbit; animation-duration:3s; 
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  transform-origin:50% 500%;
}
@keyframes orbit{
  0%{ transform:translateY(50px) rotateZ(0) }
  100%{ transform:translateY(50px) rotateZ(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<span id="curve">
  <span id="ch1">h</span>
  <span id="ch2">e</span>
  <span id="ch3">l</span>
  <span id="ch4">l</span>
  <span id="ch5">o</span>
</span>

<div id="earth">earth</div>
```